# testimonials previous button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make testimonials and next button works fine but the back(previous) button when i click first  click work but when click next and click back again the code stop working and i don't know what is the problem.........:/
here is my code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var peopleOpinion = $(".people-opinion:first");
    var peopleCount = $(".people-opinion").length; // 9 items(div)
        // one row have 3 items(div)
        // 4.5 = one click
    var clicksNum = Math.round(peopleCount / 4.5);
    var pre = $(".previous");
    var next = $(".next");
    var marginLeft = -300;
    var clicks = 1;
    next.on('click', function() {
        if (clicks <= clicksNum && !(marginLeft == 0)) {
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : marginLeft + "px"});
            marginLeft += -300;
            clicks++;
        } else if (marginLeft == 0) {
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : "-300px"});
            clicks++;
        } else {
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : "0px"});
            marginLeft = -300;
            clicks = 1;
        }
    });
    pre.on('click', function() {
        if (!(marginLeft == 0)) {
            marginLeft += 300;
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : marginLeft + "px"});
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 290px;
  border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
.container .people-opinion {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 29%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world111</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world222</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world333</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world444</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world555</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world666</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world777</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world888</div>
  <div class="people-opinion">Hello world999</div>
</div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<button class="previous">previous</button>
```

Comment: Is there an error message in your dev console?

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: are you sure there are no errors in console have you checked if there are no filters for throwing error on console, make sure they are all checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok This is the code you need .. but let me explain somethings first

first of all you'll need to know that working with `%` in css needs no margins and no padding ..  it will be better to control the percentages without margins and paddings

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var containerWidth = $('.container').width();
    var peopleOpinion = $(".people-opinion:first");
    var peopleCount = $(".people-opinion").length; // 9
    var clicksNum = peopleCount / 3;
    var pre = $(".previous");
    var next = $(".next");
    var clicks = 1;
    next.on('click', function() {
        if (clicks < clicksNum) {
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : - containerWidth * clicks + "px"});
            clicks++;
        }
    });
    pre.on('click', function() {
        var pclicks = clicksNum - clicks - 1;
        if (clicks <= clicksNum && clicks !== 1) {
            peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : + containerWidth * pclicks + "px"});
            clicks--;
        }
    });

    // if you working on a responsive website you may need to use `resize` and update the container width
    $(window).on('resize' , function(){
        containerWidth = $('.container').width();
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
.container .people-opinion {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  max-width : 33.33333333%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.people-opinion > div{
  margin : 4px;
  padding : 2px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
  <div class="people-opinion"><div>Hello world111</div></div>
</div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<button class="previous">previous</button>
```

-Explanation

- while you have margins and padding on `people-opinion` that makes you use `290px` and `29%` and its totally wrong .. use the exact width you need which should be `300px` and because of that I wrapped another div `.people-opinion > div` inside `people-opinion` and set style to it .. in my code I made it responsive so I set the container width to `100%`
- In the previous button you need to use `var pclicks = clicksNum - clicks - 1;` which gives you the right number of clicks you need to go to the previous step ..

Comment: thank you for the explanation i understood my mistake

Comment: you're welcome ya @MohamedHassan .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once `marginLeft` is 0 and `clicks` is greater than 2, the only operation that is allowed to happen is:

```
peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left" : "-300px"});
clicks++;
```

I simplified your logic a bit, and this seems to work:

```
var slot = 0;
next.on('click', function() {
    slot++;
    slot=slot%3;
    peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left": (slot*-300)+ "px"});                                                    
});
pre.on('click', function() {
    slot--;
    if (slot < 0)
      slot = 2;
    peopleOpinion.css({"margin-left": (slot*-300)+ "px"});
});
```

This can even be generalized further if we have a variable like `pages = Math.ceil(people/3)` and work with that instead of constants above.